# How do I get the id of the document I queried?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My goal is to let a student register his/her fb/google account through typing the code given to them.

How I structured the data

```js
registration-code{
  docId: {
    code:'52400028'
  }
}
```

provider.ts

```js
  checkIfRegistrationCodeExists(userTypedCode:string){
    this.registrationCodeCollectionRef = this.afDb.collection('registration-code', 
    ref => ref.where('code', '==', userTypedCode));
    this.registrationCodeCollection = this.registrationCodeCollectionRef.valueChanges();
  }
```

Then I check if it matches

```js
  checkIfRegistrationCodeExists(){
    console.log(this.userTypedCode);
```

registrationCode.ts

```js
this.registrationCodeProvider.checkIfRegistrationCodeExists(this.userTypedCode);
this.registrationCodeProvider.registrationCodeCollection.subscribe(code => {
      if(code.length = 1){
        console.log('Matched')
      } else {
        console.log('No matches');
      }
    })
  }
```

Now my problem is, how will I get the document Id of the document in question?

Any tips on how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, hehe. I would  only need to use snapshotChanges method for that since I'm still getting a collection.

```
  checkIfRegistrationCodeExists(userTypedCode:string){
    this.registrationCodeCollectionRef = this.afDb.collection('registration-code', 
    ref => ref.where('code', '==', userTypedCode));
    this.registrationCodeCollection = this.registrationCodeCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as RegistrationCode;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })), 
    );
    return this.registrationCodeCollection;
  }
```

Then I do this to get the id

```
  checkIfRegistrationCodeExists(){
    console.log(this.userTypedCode);
    this.registrationCodeProvider.checkIfRegistrationCodeExists(this.userTypedCode);
    this.registrationCodeProvider.registrationCodeCollection.subscribe(code => {
      if(code.length = 1){
        console.log('Matched', code[0].id);
      } else {
        console.log('No matches');
      }
    })
  }
```